# Timer in BackgroundAgent

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

This is a followup question to my previous question: [HttpWebRequest from AudioPlayerAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474656/httpwebrequest-from-audioplayeragent)

I am looking for a way to run a function every 20-30 seconds from inside my BackgroundAudioPlayer in order to query a web server.

Currently, I'm trying to use a timer in this fashion:

```
public AudioPlayer()
    {
        if (!_classInitialized)
        {
            _classInitialized = true;
            // Subscribe to the managed exception handler
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
            {
                Application.Current.UnhandledException += AudioPlayer_UnhandledException;

            });
            trackTimer = new Timer(TrackTimerTick, null, 0, 2000);
        }
    }
```

However, whenever I call NotifyComplete(), the timer no longer ticks. Is it possible to make this work? If so, how?

Comment: You wrote: "When I call `NotifyComplete()`, the timer no longer ticks."  Of course! `NotifyComplete()` documentation states, in the Remarks section, "this call will end background agent execution."

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to get the functionality I want?