# mediaelement keep playing after lock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mediaelement, lockscreen

I have a medialement with a url-source which streams a radio station. Everything works fine and music plays as expected! When I press the shutdown button and the phone locks, the streaming stops. How can I fix that? Even if I press the "flag" button, I see my main screen but the music stops :/
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must use the BackgroundAudioPlayer to accomplish this.

See this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for more info and [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702935/audioplayeragent-timer-and-webservice/9710014#9710014) explaining some gotchas of the BackgroundAudioPlayer

Taking the sample from the msdn link. I changed the PlayTrack method to:

```
private void PlayTrack(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
{
       var track = new AudioTrack(
                    new Uri("http://m1.onweb.gr/1055rock"),
                    "Online",
                    "Music",
                    string.Empty,
                    null,
                    string.Empty,
                    EnabledPlayerControls.Pause);
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.Track = track;
        }
}
```

And I get the errors noted below. How are you trying to start the player?

Comment: The source for the track can be a URI as well.

Comment: I set the url of the radio station as a "new AudioTrack" and although "name" and "artist" appear on the playlist (I check that by pressing up/low volume) nothing happens! No music playing or smthing :/ If I set this url in a mediaElement it works fine!

Comment: Did you add a new Windows Phone Audio Playback Agent to your solution?

Comment: yes..I think I did it right cause the song I add appears fine on the now playing menu that pops when I press volume up/down! The problem is that there is no sound :s

Comment: what is the URI you are using

Comment: I have tried all these: [link](http://m1.onweb.gr/1055rock) [link](http://m1.onweb.gr/1055rock?MSWMExt=.asf) [link](http://wm1.greekstream.net/1055) but non of them worked..

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the OnError method of your AudioPlayer you will see the following error: Message "-1072872837", HResult: -2146233088. Might have something to do with the support media for WP7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I don't get any errors.. any other ideas? how can a mediaelement stream that link and the backgroundaudio cant?

Comment: I start it this way:
`BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://m1.onweb.gr/1055rock", UriKind.Absolute), "Rock Radio", "Radio", "rock", null); BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();`